# Functional programming in Java on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, functional-programming

Does google app engine support any functional programming libraries ?

For example functionaljava : http://functionaljava.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is usefull list: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

So there is "CAL, together with the Open Quark framework, can be run on App Engine.".
At least you can embed Scala in your app to use features from functional programming.
As for "functionaljava" it's better to test important features by hands because of even supported things sometimes have strange bugs when runs on GAE.

Comment: @yahul thanks, also found this useful : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/